# Testing return value of function in Jasmine & Angular2

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In Jasmine you can check a function has been run by spying on it; you can also check what arguments have been given (if any); but how can you check what value that function returns?

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.checkString('Hello World');
}

checkString(str: string): boolean {
  if (str === 'Hello World') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Spec**

```
...
component = fixture.componentInstance;
...


it('should check string equals `Hello World` and return boolean', () => {

  let spy = spyOn(component, "checkString");

  fixture.detectChanges(); // This runs the component OnInit() which contains a call to checkString();

  expect(spy).toBeTruthy(); // <<< This line fails. How can I get the returned value of the method?

});
```

Comment: This test makes absolutely no sense. You're coupling the test far too tightly to the current implementation; what's the actual *behaviour* you want from the component? What are you going to *do* with the value that gets returned? As a rule of thumb, it's bad news to mock parts of the class you're testing, and in this specific example the return value you say you want to check is *the return value from the spy*, you're in charge of what that is! You could `.and.callThrough()`, but then why spy on it?

Comment: To test what a function returns, you call the function, store the result in a variable, and check that the variable contains what you expect it to contain. This does not involve spying. Spying is useful when component A depends on complex, separately tested service B, and you want to spy on B to check that A, the real A, behaves correctly. You're spying on A to test that A works correctly, so you're not testing your code here. You're testing Jasmine.

Comment: Both fair points; I included the `spyOn()` because I know that watches for uses of the method and thought there may be a way to use this to see what the method outputs. I accept I didn't use the right syntax for the 'failing line'.

**I want to test what value the method returns when it's run when the component initialises.** I _could_ test the method itself by calling it within a test (and not needing to spy), which requires passing in arguments. The arguments are provided within the OnInit().

Comment: You could have one test that `ngOnInit` calls it with the right thing (`expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Hello World');`) and another that tests that it returns the right result for that input (`expect(component.checkString('Hello World')).toBe(true);`). But I would argue that this isn't a particularly useful way of writing your tests. Treat the *component* as the unit - from what you've posted the call is completely pointless anyway, so you don't need to test it at all, but with a [mcve] of the actual behaviour maybe people could suggest a test that actually exercises something useful.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe that's a good point. I'll separate the tests in my code.

Comment: I don't think you're reading what I'm writing. The shortest fix is to delete the pointless code under test.